Return SUM of all cells that fit TWO CRITERIA related by POSITION
I'm able to use SUMIF to return sum of all cells that fit one criteria:
=SUMIF(DATA!$U$3:$3, "Previous Age",DATA!$U9:9)

However, I'd like to add another criteria: to match $F$2 with 1st criteria's OFFSET (,,-3).
=SUMIF(DATA!$U$4:$4, DATA!$U$3:$3&OFFSET(DATA!$U$3:$3,,-3),"Previous Age"&$F$2)

=SUMIF(DATA!$U$4:$4, (DATA!$U$3:$3="Previous Age")*(OFFSET(DATA!$U$3:$3,,-3)=$F$2))

The above two formulas do not work, but hoping it still conveys what I'm trying to do.
the cells in question are highlighted in teal.
attached is the file

In this case SUMIF can't be used as its 2nd parameter must be a valid range otherwise you will get:

ERROR Argument must be a range.

Try:
=SUM(LET(x, WRAPROWS(FILTER(DATA!U4:4, 
 REGEXMATCH(DATA!U3:3, "Previous Age|Rope Type")), 2, ), 
 IFNA(FILTER(INDEX(x,,1), INDEX(x,,2)=F$2))))


Basically it's extraction of columns wrapped into table and filtered down before summing it:


Update
=SUM(LET(x, WRAPROWS(FILTER(DATA!AA4:4, 
 REGEXMATCH(DATA!AA3:3, "Previous Age|Rope Type")), 2, ), 
 IFNA(FILTER(INDEX(x,,2), INDEX(x,,1)=F$2))))



i made a mistake in my original post. instead of OFFSET (,,1), it should be OFFSET (,,-3).  would you be able to edit to reflect this?  i tried your formula and it seems to work had my original offset amount was correct.  WRAPPROWS and REGEMATCH is completely new to me and i can't seem to make the corrected offset work with your formula

@ChulhoChang currently in your sample sheet in Current!E4 its value 382. whats expected output?

since "new england" is selected in the drop down, it should be (according to sheet: data), find all "new england" and add its offset (,,3) or if the formula finds "previous age" first then previous age and its offset (,,-3).  i highlighted the pairing in matching colors in sheet:data for clarification.

so currently, with "new england", Current!E4=122+0=122

you saved the day once again @player0.  will study up on all the functions you used that i'm not familiar with.


You may try this in Cell_E4:
=sum(ifna(filter(DATA!U4:4,DATA!$U$3:$3="Previous Age",hstack(offset(DATA!U4:4,,1),)=$F$2)))

Updated:
=sum(ifna(filter(DATA!U4:4,DATA!$U$3:$3="Previous Age",choosecols(offset(DATA!U4:4,,-3),sequence(columns(DATA!U4:4)))=$F$2)))


i made a mistake in my original post.  instead of OFFSET (,,1), it should be OFFSET (,,-3).  i tried using the formula from @rockinfreakshow with OFFSET (,,1) and i think it works as it should.  but when i make the adjustment to OFFSET (,,-3), it no longer works.

Test the updated formula & see if its giving out the expected output
